# What kinds of web apps might I want to build with the HTML5 Web Messaging spec?

Tags: html, web-applications, cross-domain

The HTML5 family of specs has several new communication capabilities, including XmlHttpRequest Level 2, Web Sockets, and Server-Sent Events.  I can easily think of examples of web apps that I might like to build with these specs.

**Edit**: Here's some examples:

- XHR2: search client, web mail, file uploader
- Web Sockets: FPS, online games, chat client, NRT traffic or weather reports
- SSE: Stock ticker, news feed, FB wall

But when it comes to the HTML5 Web Messaging spec, I can't think of any.  So what kinds of web apps might I want to build with it?  TIA.

http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently found a good use case for Web Messaging.  Many web apps are starting to authenticate using Facebook, so they open another tab with a Facebook login and communicate with the its contents.

Got a better use case?  If so, I'll unselect my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use it to communicate between tabs. For example, when capturing an electronic signature, we open the document to be signed in a new tab. When they submit the signature, I message the main tab to let it know that the signature has been submitted. This allows me to take further actions on the main tab without having to do some convoluted server-side check via polling.

Comment: +1 Cool idea.  Did you use channel messaging for that?  http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/#channel-messaging

Comment: No, I was not aware of that capability but thank you.

Comment: I'm wondering why we still even call this HTML... it's "Not your father's HTML".

Answer (score 0):

It's intended for cross-domain messaging. One big example would be Facebook apps, which currently have to communicate with Facebook via a convoluted manner as they live on a separate domain in an iframe.

Comment: But both web sockets and XHR2 are cross-domain, so that alone isn't a good reason to use web messaging.

Comment: My read of the spec is that this is a much simpler method.

Answer (score 0):

I think all these technologies enable a more responsive web design. It's just like the AJAX transition: Before the transition, users expect to see the whole page refresh; After the transition, users understand the page can be updated partially.

When the new transition is finished, users will realize that content on the page could be real-time data. That means a user is not only interacting with a website (and then wait for other users to interact with the same website). He or she could be interacting with other users because it's real-time interaction over the website.

Cross-domain support will make this more widely adopted. Because not everybody will set up their own responsive web server and real-time web application, cross-domain support will allow those not-so-dynamic websites to integrate new features from 3rd-parties.

Comment: True and interesting.  Though not exactly what I was looking for. :(